# How can I specify the encoding of Java source files?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding

I use weird Unicode strings in my Java test cases. The compiler seemingly interprets the file as iso-8859-1, causing JUnit to complain.

In Python I can specify the encoding at the top of the file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Is there an equivalent in Java? How can I detect / specify the encoding of .java files?

Comment: You cannot do this internally.

Comment: It is compiler-dependent. You may also want to look at the [native2ascii](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/index.html#intl) tool to convert the code points to Unicode escape sequences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set it when you compile the file with the parameter "-encoding"

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Answer (score 3):

The `javac` compiler has a parameter `-encoding` where you can set it.
In Eclipse you must change the project settings or the global settings for `*.java` files.

Answer (score 3):

The java compiler (javac) accepts an option -encoding.  If you are using an IDE like Eclipse you can specify the encoding in the preferences.